# puppetdb: "verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate" and "SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3/TLS write finished"

Tags: ssl, puppet

I got problems getting puppetdb connected/setup propertly to my Systems.

My Puppetversion: 6

Docs I used:

- https://puppet.com/blog/scaling-open-source-puppet/ (CVQuesty)
- https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/latest/install_via_module.html
- https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/latest/puppetdb_connection.html

**More Details:**

I installed the puppetDB like this:

```
[user@git_development]$ cat  data/nodes/puppetdb01.fqdn.yaml

puppetdb::database::postgresql: 'localhost'
puppetdb::server::database_host: 'localhost'
puppetdb::server::listen_address: '0.0.0.0'
puppetdb::server::manage_firewall: false
```

while i try to connect it from my compilers A and B (Puppetmaster minus SSL functionality) by this:

```
[user@git_development]$ cat  data/nodes/puppetcompilerA.fqdn.yaml
puppetdb::master::config::puppetdb_server: 'puppetdb01.fqdn'
```

However, if i run on the compiler "puppet agent -t" I reseive the following in repeat for several times:

```
Error: Request to https://puppetdb01.fqdn:8081/pdb/meta/v1/version failed after 0.066 seconds: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3/TLS write finished
Wrapped exception:
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3/TLS write finished
Notice: Unable to connect to puppetdb server (https://puppetdb01.fqdn:8081): Request to https://puppetdb01.fqdn:8081/pdb/meta/v1/version failed after 0.066 seconds: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3/TLS write finished
Notice: Failed to connect to puppetdb; sleeping 2 seconds before retry
```

If i check the the Cert with "echo | openssl s_client -connect puppetdb01.fqdn:8081 | openssl x509 -noout -dates"
I get:

```
depth=0 CN = puppetdb01.fqdn
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = puppetdb01.fqdn
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
140503875921728:error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2150:
notBefore=Nov 26 15:06:52 2020 GMT
notAfter=Nov 26 15:06:52 2025 GMT
```

I already tried: `puppetdb ssl-setup`
resulting in:

```
PEM files in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/ssl already exists, checking integrity.
Setting ssl-host in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-port in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-key in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-cert in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-ca-cert in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
```

and:

```
mv /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/ssl/ /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/ssl-old
puppetdb ssl-setup -f
```

resulting in:

```
PEM files in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/ssl already exists, checking integrity.
Overwriting existing PEM files due to -f flag
Copying files: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem, /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppetdb01.fqdn.pem and /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/puppetdb01.fqdn.pem to /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/ssl
Setting ssl-host in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-port in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-key in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-cert in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
Setting ssl-ca-cert in /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini already correct.
```

This is what the cert looks like:

```
[root@puppetdb01 ~]# echo | openssl s_client -connect puppetdb01.fqdn:8081 | openssl x509 -noout -text|less
```

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 8 (0x8)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = Puppet CA: puppetmaster01.fqdn
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 26 15:06:52 2020 GMT
            Not After : Nov 26 15:06:52 2025 GMT
        Subject: CN = puppetdb01.fqdn
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:bf:d6:a7:de:cd:90:99:9e:fe:c8:98:45:81:cb:
                    6a:39:b9:a7:8a:2a:b5:a7:5d:81:b6:a9:4e:a7:8f:
                    38:18:f0:5f:14:6f:7c:56:2d:fb:c1:cd:5f:78:dd:
                    94:df:30:93:2e:f1:e7:cc:e2:e0:e2:16:4e:cb:f4:
                    38:5e:f2:ad:ee:7b:25:b5:e7:64:cf:2c:12:fd:91:
                    86:56:08:f7:61:31:9c:cf:e9:9e:da:0e:96:62:87:
                    cb:07:16:eb:b7:f7:9e:f9:6d:84:98:17:95:a6:ae:
                    de:ac:ff:be:fb:91:67:27:b6:69:d1:0b:99:5b:29:
                    a6:8e:1d:7b:b6:a5:8c:f0:4a:51:9a:aa:09:68:29:
                    7a:d8:84:f7:de:23:ce:b2:79:4c:04:7e:36:55:3b:
                    bd:d0:8a:2c:5f:8e:28:3f:7d:6d:7a:a4:84:47:8a:
                    a3:db:12:35:a0:ed:ed:34:64:88:84:01:bf:98:e2:
                    e6:6a:76:94:8a:81:17:08:c4:2a:fa:67:40:8a:af:
                    65:58:45:c2:c1:2c:b0:71:f2:41:f5:ab:d0:81:1b:
                    70:ad:e2:a9:95:db:51:cb:7c:18:0d:a1:3e:80:d4:
                    e3:27:97:d9:0e:90:bc:58:3f:71:0b:ad:23:30:62:
                    69:08:53:aa:0f:80:ca:27:71:2b:39:ff:5f:2c:60:
                    5e:0f:c6:3c:87:f7:46:02:7b:1b:46:3a:6e:8e:88:
                    00:8a:1e:43:21:11:6b:08:8e:39:5c:47:dc:fe:a5:
                    b2:54:c9:69:e7:50:21:4a:39:2c:fc:2e:5c:5e:ac:
                    b2:32:d5:10:1e:f6:6a:c6:fb:fc:3e:94:14:49:6f:
                    65:24:f9:eb:50:e0:47:a2:bd:f8:b8:ca:ab:16:0a:
                    8c:9c:46:78:34:bb:12:f3:6d:c0:80:d6:24:ae:5c:
                    e4:b7:4a:3b:5c:1a:9d:53:76:18:ac:dc:88:6e:e2:
                    91:b9:af:c8:5d:c0:2a:81:8d:25:ba:b0:4c:df:04:
                    11:f0:4f:a6:ff:e3:67:04:73:e1:ac:c8:a3:67:63:
                    f2:87:80:a2:2a:c0:e5:6e:85:0a:52:61:bd:58:90:
                    5f:6e:03:76:69:68:c2:2a:82:40:f8:3b:5d:3f:4e:
                    16:80:f6:64:94:9f:b6:bc:a7:33:e9:a2:4f:d5:d3:
                    5c:4a:7a:91:26:f0:18:4c:8f:f9:6f:b4:6f:d5:b7:
                    fa:b9:f5:d2:4c:5c:5f:11:99:44:c3:5e:7b:e1:3c:
                    43:f0:d4:70:00:80:19:75:cb:3a:f7:e8:cc:4a:3d:
                    d7:9c:54:ee:60:cf:a4:c7:54:78:0d:91:ed:ea:0d:
                    9e:bc:50:db:52:b7:ad:dd:07:22:e7:f3:89:b6:60:
                    8b:e6:0f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            Netscape Comment:
                Puppet Server Internal Certificate
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:77:79:6F:EE:E9:5E:9F:AF:64:B7:88:6F:F2:4A:86:3B:65:DF:85:00            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                BD:FE:BC:0F:8E:AF:03:7F:EA:CE:49:B0:B4:55:99:92:BD:1A:05:50
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         73:ca:90:37:50:b7:1a:30:2e:8f:e5:85:a0:c5:6a:b9:86:c1:
         df:54:67:57:e8:21:a7:93:44:f5:9b:89:e7:dd:f1:a9:cc:93:
         b3:33:d4:88:8d:1e:fb:60:48:cc:4d:5f:1f:6d:14:71:b6:fa:
         15:17:f2:9c:a6:76:42:d7:67:df:4a:c6:28:e8:a7:2f:23:5a:
         38:94:36:2e:73:c6:c2:30:99:63:b0:a1:1e:96:2a:86:c6:23:
         2b:5c:47:23:73:1b:0f:c7:52:36:93:d5:d5:02:f8:04:f9:1e:
         60:63:63:b4:a8:8d:cb:3d:2f:e8:be:eb:d4:c5:42:24:0a:cb:
         6b:ad:60:94:35:fb:3f:89:67:7f:00:23:c7:32:e1:cf:80:6a:
         fa:7b:6a:55:01:de:a1:df:48:03:d7:ae:b6:af:56:8c:60:ba:
         b5:19:c8:0a:e8:a6:24:49:1c:76:44:6b:c2:47:c8:a5:8c:9a:
         d9:fe:4f:44:fe:6d:bc:64:f4:14:e0:6e:19:74:34:b6:bf:df:
         1f:bc:b9:3d:1f:97:97:f6:7d:96:e9:79:07:e9:a7:dc:79:99:
         e5:23:bf:48:66:df:34:16:60:f0:ab:db:62:4f:64:22:5e:6a:
         41:d2:53:b7:c5:dd:83:1a:a7:79:88:f9:3f:95:c7:90:06:f8:
         ac:02:7b:a1:16:21:68:52:e1:39:07:31:75:e0:91:f2:82:fc:
         c1:05:a9:24:8d:6a:c9:b9:dc:69:b9:a2:dd:66:88:c0:6c:24:
         48:39:71:59:70:4a:04:bc:24:43:11:00:9f:27:1b:d4:cd:f3:
         c8:4a:96:c7:00:4a:3a:5d:3b:35:68:52:26:cc:db:fa:af:65:
         bd:00:a3:4f:c0:a3:09:f3:74:a9:2a:d4:42:a5:17:bf:89:7f:
         8e:34:e3:11:dd:cb:cc:96:28:05:c7:bd:99:67:2f:f6:3d:9e:
         a2:3a:b0:4b:22:6f:3a:fe:e0:5c:ef:bd:81:d9:4d:e4:24:77:
         6d:d3:3b:38:c8:3b:e8:b5:58:09:de:97:e8:a8:ac:ca:83:33:
         a2:b9:8d:4e:c2:7a:e6:d6:fe:53:6f:ec:a7:e2:42:be:f7:0e:
         53:16:58:3a:a0:71:42:88:8a:fc:b3:fb:f8:8a:7b:9c:1e:a1:
         b2:7c:f5:5a:11:fd:a3:25:d4:f1:59:a8:05:40:11:1f:87:ca:
         e2:75:43:07:36:10:78:dc:50:dd:47:68:1e:4a:ef:91:43:15:
         24:15:85:40:89:af:c5:85:35:68:d9:a6:57:f1:fa:f5:55:4c:
         29:80:c0:1b:25:12:b1:a1:3f:21:b8:d3:8a:05:fe:5e:13:f1:
         27:66:28:78:6e:ac:17:79
```

My Hostfile looks like this:

```
# Hosts File for Scaled Puppet Community Implementation
# Master
x.x.x.a    puppetmaster01.fqdn      puppetmaster01 puppet# Load Balancer
x.x.x.b    puppetlb01.fqdn  puppetlb01# Compilers
x.x.x.c    puppetcompiler01.fqdn    puppetcompiler01
x.x.x.d    puppetcompiler02.fqdn    puppetcompiler02# PuppetDB
x.x.x.e    puppetdb01.fqdn          puppetdb01
```

The logs on the puppetbd look like this on start:

```
2020-12-27T10:44:15.541+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.log] Logging initialized @5614ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2020-12-27T10:44:16.452+01:00 INFO  [p.t.s.s.scheduler-service] Initializing Scheduler Service
2020-12-27T10:44:16.482+01:00 INFO  [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory] Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2020-12-27T10:44:16.494+01:00 INFO  [o.q.c.SchedulerSignalerImpl] Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2020-12-27T10:44:16.494+01:00 INFO  [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.1 created.
2020-12-27T10:44:16.495+01:00 INFO  [o.q.s.RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.
2020-12-27T10:44:16.496+01:00 INFO  [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler] Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.1) 'd015e262-bf79-4fe0-8949-d3c5843a40d5' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

2020-12-27T10:44:16.496+01:00 INFO  [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'd015e262-bf79-4fe0-8949-d3c5843a40d5' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2020-12-27T10:44:16.496+01:00 INFO  [o.q.i.StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.1
2020-12-27T10:44:16.496+01:00 INFO  [o.q.c.QuartzScheduler] Scheduler d015e262-bf79-4fe0-8949-d3c5843a40d5_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2020-12-27T10:44:16.497+01:00 INFO  [p.t.s.w.jetty9-service] Initializing web server(s).
2020-12-27T10:44:16.551+01:00 INFO  [p.p.pdb-routing] Starting PuppetDB, entering maintenance mode
2020-12-27T10:44:16.588+01:00 INFO  [p.t.s.s.status-service] Registering status callback function for service 'puppetdb-status', version 6.13.1
2020-12-27T10:44:16.592+01:00 WARN  [p.t.s.m.jolokia] Metrics access control using trapperkeeper-authorization is disabled. Add the authorization service to the trapperkeeper bootstrap configuration file to enable it.
2020-12-27T10:44:16.619+01:00 INFO  [p.t.s.n.nrepl-service] nREPL service disabled, not starting
2020-12-27T10:44:16.620+01:00 INFO  [p.t.s.w.jetty9-service] Starting web server(s).
2020-12-27T10:44:16.795+01:00 INFO  [p.t.s.w.jetty9-core] Starting web server.
2020-12-27T10:44:16.799+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.Server] jetty-9.4.28.v20200408; built: 2020-04-08T17:49:39.557Z; git: ab228fde9e55e9164c738d7fa121f8ac5acd51c9; jvm 1.8.0_272-b10
2020-12-27T10:44:16.833+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler] Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@7267b9f2{/pdb,null,AVAILABLE}
2020-12-27T10:44:16.844+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.session] DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-12-27T10:44:16.844+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.session] No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-12-27T10:44:16.846+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.session] node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2020-12-27T10:44:16.870+01:00 INFO  [p.t.s.m.jolokia] Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml
2020-12-27T10:44:16.906+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler] Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1d8e2699{/metrics/v2,null,AVAILABLE}
2020-12-27T10:44:16.925+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.AbstractConnector] Started ServerConnector@66163948{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-12-27T10:44:16.933+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] x509=X509@51ddbe91(private key,h=[puppetdb01.a.ht-haj-a.de.vier.services],w=[]) for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.980+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.980+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.980+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.981+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory] No Cipher matching 'TLS_SRP_SHA_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA' is supported
2020-12-27T10:44:16.983+01:00 WARN  [o.e.j.u.s.S.config] Weak cipher suite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA enabled for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.983+01:00 WARN  [o.e.j.u.s.S.config] Weak cipher suite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA enabled for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.983+01:00 WARN  [o.e.j.u.s.S.config] Weak cipher suite TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA enabled for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.984+01:00 WARN  [o.e.j.u.s.S.config] Weak cipher suite TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA enabled for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.984+01:00 WARN  [o.e.j.u.s.S.config] Weak cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 enabled for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.984+01:00 WARN  [o.e.j.u.s.S.config] Weak cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA enabled for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.984+01:00 WARN  [o.e.j.u.s.S.config] Weak cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA enabled for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.984+01:00 WARN  [o.e.j.u.s.S.config] Weak cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 enabled for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.984+01:00 WARN  [o.e.j.u.s.S.config] Weak cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA enabled for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.984+01:00 WARN  [o.e.j.u.s.S.config] Weak cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA enabled for InternalSslContextFactory@21fe4cf5[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
2020-12-27T10:44:16.985+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.AbstractConnector] Started ServerConnector@35095b52{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2020-12-27T10:44:16.985+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.Server] Started @7060ms
2020-12-27T10:44:16.989+01:00 INFO  [p.t.s.s.status-core] Starting background monitoring of cpu usage metrics
2020-12-27T10:44:16.994+01:00 INFO  [p.t.s.s.status-service] Registering status callback function for service 'status-service', version 1.1.1
2020-12-27T10:44:16.995+01:00 INFO  [p.t.s.s.status-service] Registering status service HTTP API at /status
2020-12-27T10:44:17.021+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler] Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@4861f3ac{/status,null,AVAILABLE}
2020-12-27T10:44:17.023+01:00 INFO  [p.p.dashboard] Redirecting / to the PuppetDB dashboard
2020-12-27T10:44:17.024+01:00 INFO  [o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler] Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@2f5fe21e{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2020-12-27T10:44:17.027+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] PuppetDB version 6.13.1
2020-12-27T10:44:17.029+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Ensuring default database is up to date
2020-12-27T10:44:17.033+01:00 INFO  [c.z.h.HikariDataSource] PDBMigrationsPool: default - Starting...
2020-12-27T10:44:17.048+01:00 INFO  [c.z.h.HikariDataSource] PDBMigrationsPool: default - Start completed.
2020-12-27T10:44:17.154+01:00 WARN  [p.p.c.services] PostgreSQL 9.6 is deprecated. Please upgrade to PostgreSQL 11
2020-12-27T10:44:17.172+01:00 INFO  [p.p.s.migrate] Locking migrations table before migrating
2020-12-27T10:44:17.197+01:00 INFO  [p.p.s.migrate] Updating table statistics for: value_types, report_statuses
2020-12-27T10:44:17.211+01:00 INFO  [c.z.h.HikariDataSource] PDBMigrationsPool: default - Shutdown initiated...
2020-12-27T10:44:17.224+01:00 INFO  [c.z.h.HikariDataSource] PDBMigrationsPool: default - Shutdown completed.
2020-12-27T10:44:17.225+01:00 INFO  [c.z.h.HikariDataSource] PDBReadPool - Starting...
2020-12-27T10:44:17.226+01:00 INFO  [c.z.h.HikariDataSource] PDBReadPool - Start completed.
2020-12-27T10:44:17.240+01:00 WARN  [p.p.c.services] PostgreSQL 9.6 is deprecated. Please upgrade to PostgreSQL 11
2020-12-27T10:44:17.258+01:00 INFO  [c.z.h.HikariDataSource] PDBWritePool - Starting...
2020-12-27T10:44:17.259+01:00 INFO  [c.z.h.HikariDataSource] PDBWritePool - Start completed.
2020-12-27T10:44:17.285+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Starting sweep of stale nodes (threshold: 7 days)
2020-12-27T10:44:17.286+01:00 INFO  [p.p.pdb-routing] PuppetDB finished starting, disabling maintenance mode
2020-12-27T10:44:17.321+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Finished sweep of stale nodes (threshold: 7 days)
2020-12-27T10:44:17.322+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Starting purge deactivated and expired nodes (threshold: 14 days)
2020-12-27T10:44:17.326+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Finished purge deactivated and expired nodes (threshold: 14 days)
2020-12-27T10:44:17.329+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Starting sweep of stale reports (threshold: 14 days) and resource events (threshold: 14 days)
2020-12-27T10:44:17.353+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Finished sweep of stale reports (threshold: 14 days) and resource events (threshold: 14 days)
2020-12-27T10:44:17.354+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Starting gc packages
2020-12-27T10:44:17.380+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Finished gc packages
2020-12-27T10:44:17.380+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Starting database garbage collection
2020-12-27T10:44:17.404+01:00 INFO  [p.p.c.services] Finished database garbage collection
2020-12-27T10:44:18.376+01:00 INFO  [p.d.version-check] Newer version 7.0.1 is available! Visit https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/latest/release_notes.html for details.
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Can anybody help me or at least point me to the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my Problem was the following:
I added to the Hiera file, representing my compilers:

```
puppetdb::master::config::strict_validation: false
```